Изменение стандартной темы Gnome
OS Arch linux (wayland | gnome 46)
В утилите Gradience сделал палитру, которая мне нужна, но не везде применились цвета которые мне нужны. К примеру, цвета не изменились:

в терминале в строке ввода
в выпадающих меню верхней панели (дата, язык, и в секторе где кнопки выключения, изенения звука, не поменялся background и цвета кнопок)
в файловом менеджере и настройках - левая панель
Так же как изменить background при входе в систему, при вводе пароля

полностью цвета применились к приложениям (календарь, калькулятор, code, доп.настройки и тд)
Все цвета которые не изменяются через Gradience меняются путем выбора стандартных "светлая" "темная" тем. Возможно ли поменять эти стандартные цвета темы вручную?
Читал что можно изменить тему Adwaita перейдя по /usr/share/themes, но у меня там нет соответствующей папки (скрытые файлы и папки отображаются)
Есть вариант полностью изменить тему Adwaita, под свои цвета, чтобы при переустановке, заменить стандартную тему на свою
Приложения без полного изменения цветов


Приложения с полным изменением цветов

